# how to play mp3 audio stored im mysql blob using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, blob

I have stored small 100kb mp3 files in mysql db as blob using phpMyAdmin

However i am unable to output it on html and play the audio...here is my code

```
require ('mysqli_connect.php'); //contains database connection


$sql="SELECT  sound FROM english WHERE eWord LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' OR kWord LIKE '%" . $name ."%'";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

   $sound=$row['sound'];

   echo '<audio controls>';
      echo    '<source src="data:audio/mp3;base64,'.$row['sound'].'">';
   echo '</audio>';
```

What actually happens is that on loading the page in xampp localhost
grayed out html audio player comes and doesn't play anything

[image]

Here is how blob looks in my phpMyAdmin
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the content of the `blob` content you are testing?

Comment: yes..but how ... i am totally new to mysql and php

Comment: @BenPearlKahan Can you please help me out..i am really stuck here and need help badly...

Comment: Did you try to base64_encode the blob before outputting it?

Comment: No.. i have no idea how to do that... can you give example how to do it

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to set your audio source as a data uri and in the it you specify the data is base64 encoded but use binary data.
You'll have to convert that to base64 encoded data

```
echo    '<source src="data:audio/mpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['sound']).'">';
```

Comment: I tried that but its not working... audio player remains greyed out and i am unable to play anything.

Comment: `echo '<audio controls>';
echo    '<source src="data:audio/mp3;base64,'.base64_encode($row['sound']).'">';
echo '</audio>';' ` But its not working...

Comment: I even tried `echo    '<source src="data:audio/mp3;base64,'.base64_encode($sound).'">';` but even that didn't work

Comment: Try changing the mime type to `audio/mpeg`

Comment: it made no difference, player remains greyed out only... can isend you entire code.. i need help badly please....

Comment: Developer console properties shows this: (in properies) **currentSrc: "data:audio/mpeg;base64,"** it is not detecting $row['sound'] as source at all. is it wrong blob file database?

Comment: that row could be empty, from the screenshot only one of the 3 sound blobs had data.

Comment: blob added to all rows... its not empty anymore still same problem

Comment: **ERROR: GET http://localhost/KachhiDict/base64_encode($sound) 404 (Not Found)** Help

Comment: last time when i clicked copy audio address it showed only **data:audio/mpeg;base64,** but now it shows `data:audio/mpeg;base64,//qUYA/ZAAADMVFGaYEbYDggGLkAAAAIrN0phgxLQN.......`

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your database not returning correct data in the blob, try this:

```
function processmusic($song){
    global $db_user, $db_password, $db_name, $db_host;
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$db_name.';host='.$db_host.'';
    try {
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $db_user, $db_password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    if (($result = $db->query('SELECT music FROM music WHERE `name` = "'.$song.'"')) !== false) {
        return '<div content="Content-Type: audio/mp3">
                    <audio controls="controls" preload="metadata" autoplay>
                        <source src="data:audio/mp3;base64,'.base64_encode($result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)).'"/>;
                    </audio>
                </div>';
    } else {
        // actions to take if it fails
    }
}
```

I found the PDO method worked for video and audio whereas without it I had nothing but issues. My only problem with this is I can't skip to time in the song. It plays but the timer is at the far right counting up. This is a limitation of the browser I am using after some trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$id=1 //id of the music file
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT content FROM music WHERE id='$id'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
header("Content-type: audio/mp3");
header("Content-transfer-encoding:binary");
header("Accept-Ranges:bytes");
echo $row['content'];
?>
```

This worked for me!!!!

Answer (score 0):

the correct form is the following::

```
<audio controls="controls" preload="metadata" autoplay>
    <source src="data:audio/mpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['audio']); ?>"/>
</audio>
```

just change the name of the column that contains the blob

Comment: Contains what? This answer looks like you lost interest and gave up part way thr