# How to output an audio file from mysql onto my index.php page

Tags: php, mysqli

So I am able to upload mp3 files onto mysql, and I am now trying to output the mp3 file onto my index page from the user who uploaded it. I made a page called Post.php and here is the code:

```
<?php
class Post {
    private $user_obj;
    private $con;

    public function __construct($con, $user)
    {
        $this->con = $con;
        $this->user_obj = new User($con, $user);
    }
    public function loadPostsFriends() {
            $str = "";
            $data = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE 
            deleted='no' ORDER BY id DESC");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $file = $row['file'];
                $file_open = fopen($file, "a+");
                $added_by = $row['added_by'];
                $date_time = $row['date_added'];
            $str .= "<div class='status_post'>
                            <div class='post_profile_pic'>
                                <img src='$profile_pic' width='50'>
                            </div>

                            <div class='posted_by'>
                                <a href='$added_by'> $username </a> $user_to 
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$time_message
                            </div>
                            <div id='post_file'>
                                <audio controls>
                                    <source src='echo fgets($file_open);' 
                                     type='audio/mpeg'>
                                    </source>
                                    fclose($file_open);
                                </audio><br>
                            </div>

                        </div>";
            }

            echo $str;
        }
}

<?
```

And here is the output code on my index page:

```
<?php 
    $post = new Post($con, $userLoggedIn);
    $post->loadPostsFriends();
?>
```

I excluded the code for $added_by and $date_time, but all the information gets outputted to the index page, except for the audio file. I am not sure how to retrieve the audio file from mysqli and display it in the audio tags so people can press play and listen to it. I know it connects to the file, but just does not display it.

Comment: if you have the audio stored in a blob you can use the HTML5 player by base64 encoding it into the src:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623814/how-to-play-mp3-audio-stored-im-mysql-blob-using-php

Comment: I tried doing what they said but unfortunately it did not work.