Is it possible that stream mp3 as blob?
I wrote a simple code that PHP sends mp3 data as blob and in client side (JS) html5 audio object plays it but the problem is : first whole of file should be fetched and then audio can be played.
function blob(uri){

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url:uri,


        success:function(result){

            let binary = convertDataURIToBinary(result);
            let blob = new Blob([binary], {type : 'audio/mp3'});
            let uri= URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            audio.src = uri;
            audio.load();

            audio.play().then(

            r => {
                
                //do something
            }

            ).catch((error) => {

                checkInternet();
            });
    

        }});

}


Blockquote

So my question : is it possible that I send data as blob and before sending whole file, audio plays? or I have to implement a client js player myself to do that?

The question is, why did you send the data as base64, instead of just the original file data?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623814/how-to-play-mp3-audio-stored-im-mysql-blob-using-php

Don't use base64.. that adds 33% overhead for no benefit.  Also, your content type is wrong, it should be audio/mpeg.  Also, there's no reason to use jQuery these days... the Fetch API will work just fine.  In any case, if you just made a simple GET request instead, you could let the audio element play back this URL directly, and it'd stream it, without any extra effort on your part.

@brad jQuery or base64 are not matter! The problem is when I'm using the blob, the whole file should be fetched. My question is that blob format can be streamed or not?

No, the Blob is immutable.  As I said, make this a GET request instead and let the audio element stream it for you.
